# PM Order change status to TECO - BAPI - VB ABAP

Tags: vb6, abap, saprfc, bapi

My code ends with the `MsgBox "TECO FuBa Call false!"`.

The `LogOn` and `Logout` functions are working fine, and when I test the function module `BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN` via SAP GUI transaction code `SE37`, everything works fine.

I have already checked: 
[PM Order change status to TECO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358873/pm-order-change-status-to-teco/58406764)

```
Public Sub teco()
Dim auftr As String
Dim teco_date As Date
teco_date = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")
auftr = "000123456789"    

Dim oFuBa As Object
Set oFuBa = Nothing
Set oFuBa = objBAPIControl.Add("BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN")

' EXPORTING
Dim e_import As Variant
Set e_import = oFuBa.Exports("IV_MMSRV_EXTERNAL_MAINTENACE")
e_import.Value = ""

' TABLES
Dim t_methods_data As Variant
Set t_methods_data = oFuBa.Tables("IT_METHODS")

Dim Row As Object
Set Row = t_methods_data.Rows.Add
Row("REFNUMBER") = "0001"
Row("OBJECTTYPE") = "HEADER"
Row("METHOD") = "TECHNICALCOMPLETE"
Row("OBJECTKEY") = auftr

Set Row = t_methods_data.Rows.Add
Row("REFNUMBER") = "0001"
Row("OBJECTTYPE") = ""
Row("METHOD") = "SAVE"
Row("OBJECTKEY") = auftr

MsgBox CStr(t_methods_data.RowCount)

Dim t_header_data As Variant
Set t_header_data = oFuBa.Tables("IT_HEADER")

Set Row = t_header_data.Rows.Add
Row("ORDERID") = auftr
Row("TECO_REF_DATE") = CStr(teco_date)
Row("TECO_REF_TIME") = "00:00:00"

MsgBox CStr(t_header_data.RowCount)

Dim t_return As Variant
Set t_return = oFuBa.Tables("RETURN")

If oFuBa.Call = True Then
    If t_return.RowCount > 0 Then
            If t_return.Cell(1, 1) = "E" Then
                Dim oFuBa2 As Object
                Set oFuBa2 = objBAPIControl.Add("BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK")
                If oFuBa2.Call = True Then
                    t_methods_data.Rows.Remove
                    t_methods_data.Rows.Remove
                    t_header_data.Rows.Remove
                End If
            Else
                Dim oFuBa3 As Object
                Set oFuBa3 = objBAPIControl.Add("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT")
                If oFuBa3.Call = True Then
                    MsgBox "TECO commit true!"
                Else
                    MsgBox "TECO commit false!"
                End If
            End If
            MsgBox "Ende Teco!"
    Else
            MsgBox "Ende TECO return False!"
    End If
Else
       If oFuBa.Exception <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Exception: " & oFuBa.Exception
        End If
            MsgBox "TECO FuBa Call false!"
End If
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What contains `oFuBa.Exception` ?

Comment: Is this VBA or maybe VB6? There is no Variant datatype in vb.net.

Comment: It is in VB6 and I will check the Exception. Can I add it when the bapi in sap has no entry under exception?

Comment: I have added the block for the exception but get no exception thrown out! `If oFuBa.Exception <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Exception: " & oFuBa.Exception
        End If
 `

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok, so maybe these points help.

- You cant TECO order when creating it. You can only TECO and exiting order. Change only.
- If you have a header notification ( AFIH-QMNUM ) try using method = 'TECO_WITH_NOTIF' instead of 'TECHNICALCOMPLETE'